# how to shade area between 2 graphs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How to use Matlab to shade the area between the upper line and the lower line?  thank you!

```
clc; clear
upper=[54.48 62.83  46.53   44.11   46.33   49.95   53.68   58.03   62.99 69.33];
lower=[54.48 45.65  40.37   40.87   42.38   44.99   47.65   50.70   53.92 57.89];
t=[0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5];
plot(t,upper);
hold on;
plot(t,lower);
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what the expected output is and what you can produce with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a polygon:

```
t_area = [t, t(end:-1:1)];
y_area= [lower, upper(end:-1:1)];
fill(t_area, y_area, 'y');
```

Here we just "stick" the two sequences of points together so that we go from left to right for the lower part, than left to right for the upper part which creates a nice polygon that is bounded by the two curves.

Comment: Would you be able to add the resulting figure?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to MATLAB right now, so anyone else can run the code feel free to add it!